# Get Folder Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in Javascript that we can get a folder in the root folder to a variable then use .getFiles() to get the files in that folder?

I worked with scripting in Photoshop with Javascript and these codes works:

```
Destination = Folder ('G:/My Projects/Project 2/Sounds');
Files = Destination.getFiles();
```

But in web developing it does not work. Is there a way? Thank you.

Is there a way that I can use paths like ('/Sounds') ?

Comment: you are mixing 2 environments together ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For your web browser, the root of the folder starts at html page you are serving. Only those directories and sub-directories which lie within the same folder as the html page can be accessed. To achieve what you desire, you probably need to write a server too.

yeah. if you have following directory structure

```
/(root1)
|--file1
/(root)
 |--index.html
 |--dir1/
 |--dir2/
 \--dir3/
   |--file
```

Only `dir1`,`dir2` and `dir3` contents can be accessed. `file1` can't be accessed.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use paths like ('/Sounds') ?

Comment: yeah. if you have following directory structure
    /
     |--index.html
     |--dir1/
     |--dir2/
     \--dir3/
       |--file

Comment: Hi, can you show me the right way for the 'syntax' ? Like if I want to access dir3, I use 'Destination = Folder('dir3')' ?

Comment: what exactly is the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't allow you to access the file system due to security reasons.

What if any page you visit could do this?

```
// over simplified example
var passwords = File('C:/passwords.txt');
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can use paths like ('/Sounds') ?

Comment: You can look at a directory through the browser using the [file protocol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). For example `file://path/to/Sounds`